# Trying to make keydown number turn red if wrong in comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown

Can someone please help implement something in my javascript project? @http://codepen.io/urketadic/pen/YpLgBX
I want number to turn red if its wrong and not in sequence with pi. Its really difficult for me to keep count and compare with everything.

I've tried a lot of this and at the end I've come up with this code:

```
 var count = 0;
// color the mistake right away
   $("#inputsm").keyup(function(event) {
    var pressed = event.key;
    answer = $("#inputsm").val();
    pisub = pi.substr(input,answer.length)
    if (pressed!=="Backspace"&&pressed!=="Delete") count++;
    else count--;
     console.log(count);
});
```

I'm just confused, i don't know how i can do this. Also does text area even allow numbers to turn red? I've tried adding jquery css as well but it doesn't work. Can someone write it in their own codepen and post a link?

Comment: Maybe `contenteditable`? http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/native-rich-text-editing-with-the-contenteditable-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ebv5n64j/2/

I've put together something that does basically what you are trying to do. You can modify it from there but that is the basic concept. I designed mine to not let the user continue until they get it right, but you could easily change that.

This is a snippet, but jsfiddle has the complete working version:

```
// If it's a delete command
  if(code === 8){
    if(!$("#wrong").length > 0)
        inputCount = (inputCount === 0 ? 0 : --inputCount);
    $("#pi span").last().remove();
    console.log(inputCount);
  } else if (code >= 48 && code <= 57) {

    var inputNumber = code - 48;
    var numSpan;

    $("#wrong").remove();

    numSpan = $("<span>"); // make a new one

    // Append the number
    numSpan.text(inputNumber);
    numSpan.removeClass("incorrect");

    if(String(inputNumber) === piDigits[inputCount]){
        numSpan.addClass("correct");
      inputCount++;
    } else {
        numSpan.attr("id", "wrong");
    }

    $("#pi").append(numSpan);

    placeCaretAtEnd(this);

  }
```

Comment: How to let user continue even if they did get it wrong? It would be nice for numbers only to be allowed but if they are right they are green if not they are red.

Comment: oh so pretty much just removing var last = $("#pi span").last(); 
But i am having trouble adding this to my own project ^^  in codepen. I am not good with this :[

Comment: It's all in standard JS so it should translate well. If you get stuck post your pen and I'll see if I can't help you out.

Comment: I am stuck for almost a day and its really confusing me because i don't know how to intergrate it with my current code. If you go to http://codepen.io/urketadic/pen/zoaRgd you will see that in options i have added a starting number from where he can start counting the pi. I think you could fix it in few mins.

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused as to what else you want it to do

Comment: I want to implement what you made into my current codepen (http://codepen.io/urketadic/pen/YpLgBX) not the one above, that was just a test.

So if you see, i have currently options and i can descide from which decimal i want to start counting. When i make a mistake the screen turns red but thats not what i want. I would like what you made to be added, so the number turns red if its wrong and its green if its correct. 

My friend wants to learn 100k and says this will work the best for him. I will remove submit button if this gets added.

Comment: Iv tried doing it myself on the text project here
http://codepen.io/urketadic/pen/zoaRgd?editors=1010

But its not really working good. Starting number seems to be working but then when i remove the numbers with backspace it will not be at the accurate count number.
For example if i type 2nd number which is 4 its going to work but then if i press delete button and go back 4 wont be the beggining number anymore, if you understand what i mean.

Comment: That has to do with the input count. Make sure the input count is restricted to the range of the starting position. Additionally, make sure the input count starts at the right value. You are close.

Comment: You can look at http://codepen.io/urketadic/pen/zoaRgd?editors=1011 iv saved it now.
Can you fix it somehow? The sooner the program is made the sooner my friend can start learning PI for world record. Now, pretty much this is the only problem. I dont have nearly as much javascript experience to fix this any time soon.

Comment: Youl notice iv also made some chances in your code like adding my pisub for starting number, also adding inputCount++ for incorrect number aswell

Comment: like for some reason its working if i press backspace once and then re-enter number
but if i press backspace few times, it messes up everything
right numbers are no longer correct.

Comment: I seem to have fixed it so.. only one line was causing all this mess.

Answer (score 1):

So I looked at your pen and thought that you were somewhat over-complicating the solution. I think a better way would be to compare the string of the input textarea with the substring of pi. Anyways, here's the fixed code and I've linked to the pen with the working version.

By the way, you mention in the description that if they want to start at the number 4 in 3.14 they should type in 1 (for index 1), but you take their input and subtract it by 1, so it essentially starts them off at 1 instead of 4, if they typed in 1.

```
$("#inputsm").keyup(function() {
 var thisLength = parseInt(input) + $(this).val().length - 1;
 if($(this).val().trim() === pi.substring(parseInt(input), thisLength)) {
    console.log("good so far!");
   $(this).removeAttr('style');
 } else {
   console.log("ahhh no good!");
   $(this).css('background', 'red');
 }
});
```

http://codepen.io/msafi/pen/dOKogK/

Comment: It doesnt work though if i add higher numbers than 2 in options tho

Comment: @UrosTadic my bad, I just updated the code and fixed it now. Looks like it was processing the input variable as a string rather than an int. parseInt fixed the issue.